extracting a row from a cell-array
I have a cell-array in which contains some information on how to process some data, like the following:
C = [
    {{1 2 3} true 0 0 5 false}; ...
    {{2 3 4} true 0 0 3 false} ...
]

How can I extract each row into its own cell array to get:
C1 = {{1 2 3} true 0 0 5 false}


You don't want to do this. Taking a cell array which can be easily indexed and turning it into named numbered variables like C1, C2, C3, etc. for different rows is almost always a bad idea as it greatly complicates downstream coding.  You can't put those C1, C2, C3, etc. variables easily into loops without the use of eval() for instance. Or you wind up copying & pasting sections of code that process C1 to process C2, etc. You need to ask yourself why you think you need to do this. What downstream code do you think needs this?

As a follow-up, cell array indexing is very cheap and fast to perform because MATLAB simply copies pointers into new variables. There is no deep data copy involved.  So indexing downstream in your code will not cost you much in performance.

@James while I agree, two big comments might be overkill to discourage something which could have just been for the sake of example

@JamesTursa each row in the cell-array is a set of instructions for a single iteration for a simulation. Since the simulation is in its own file and I don't want to throw around with redundant indices and globals, extracting each line and passing it to the simulation seems the cleanest solution to me without major refactoring.

To slice a cell array and get a cell array output, you should use round parenthesis
C1 = C(1,:);

With cell arrays, parentheses will return a subset of that cell array as a cell array, while curly braces will unpack whatever is "inside" the element(s) you're indexing.
So
C = {1, 2, 3};

% Brace indexing unpacks the data from "inside" the cell elements
C{1} = 1         % numeric scalar
C{[1,2]} = 1, 2  % two unpacked outputs which are numeric scalars
C{:} = 1, 2, 3   % three unpacked outputs which are numeric scalars

% Parentheses returns a cell array sliced from the original
C(1) = {1}       % cell element
C([1,2]) = {1,2} % 1x2 cell array
C(1,:) = {1,2,3} % 1x3 cell array

You can wrap brace indexing in more braces like {C{1,:}} but all you're doing is unpacking the cell array and then putting it into a new cell array, when you could just take the slice C(1,:).

The same logic applies to table indexing; parentheses take a slice and retain the original data type while braces get the unpacked contents
T = table([1;2],{'a';'b'})
  2×2 table
    Var1    Var2 
    ____    _____
     1      {'a'}
     2      {'b'}

T(1,2) = 
  table
    Var2 
    _____
    {'a'}

T{1,2} = {'a'} % cell array
T{1,1} = 1     % numeric scalar


The intuitive way of using C{1,:} unpacks the elements into different outputs like
[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6] = C{1,:};

To get those values back into a cell you need to use
C1 = {C{1,:}};

with the desired outcome.
Be careful about using [] instead, since the unpacking of cell-arrays is iterative, i.e.
C1 = [C{1,:}];

would result in {1 2 3 true 0 0 5 false}

{C{1,:}}  unpacks and then repacks. Much easier to use C(1,:)

@LuisMendo wow, that is literally the only way I didn't try, thx
